# Error cordova build with org.chromium.bluetoothsocket plugin

Tags: cordova, bluetooth-socket

I get a build error after adding the plugin org.chromium.bluetoothsocket:

```html
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:720: The following erro
r occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:734: Compile failed; see 
the compiler error output for details.
...
C:\OpenServer\domains\testcordova\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js: 126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:\OpenServer\domain
s\testcordova\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir
=ant-gen
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\OpenServer\domains\testcordova\pl
atforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
```

And a java compile error:

```html
...
[javac]     constructor PluginResult.PluginResult(Status) is not applicable
    [javac]       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    [javac] C:\OpenServer\domains\testcordova\platforms\android\src\org\chromium
\ChromeBluetoothSocket.java:272: error: no suitable constructor found for Plugin
Result(Status,List<PluginResult>)
    [javac]     PluginResult result = new PluginResult(status, multipartMessage);
...
```

1. You know how to get rid of this error?
2. Is there an alternative to this plugin?

Thanks!

Comment: seems the plugin version does not match with the cordova version, which version of cordova are you using and are you writing a url when you add the plugin or just org.chromium.bluetoothsocket?

Comment: According to the plugin description (http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.bluetoothsocket): 1) Engine Number must be >=3.0.0. My version is 4.2.0.  2) For adding I use: `cordova plugin add org.chromium.bluetoothsocket`. Is this wrong?

Comment: No, seems fine. Sorry I haven't used this plugin. As it seems very young, maybe it isn't finalised yet. Maybe you should open an issue in the github of the project to ask for help : https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-bluetoothSocket/issues